# index.html is not working in apache document root

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

I have got Ubuntu 12.04. I have a file `index.html` in apache'd document root but apache lists all the files when I access the document root from the browser.

It works fine if I replace `index.html` by `index.php`.

My `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /home/test/www
<Directory /home/test/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>



    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options   MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>

          DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm

</IfModule>
```

I did lot of searching but don't know my why `index.html` is not working and is getting listed in the browser.

If I keep both the files (index.html and index.php), then index.php works fine.

Here is the output of `ls -l /home/test/www`:

```
total 1816236
-rw-r--r--  1 root   www-data          3 Jun  3 10:09 index.html
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data         53 Mar  4 16:55 index.php
drwxrwsr-x  5 ubuntu www-data       4096 May 12 05:03 lifetimeholidays
-rw-r--r--  1 root   www-data 1859796992 May 29 10:32 magentolive17_4_2014.zip
drwxrwsr-x 15 ubuntu www-data       4096 May 28 15:22 railsapp
drwxr-sr-x 15 root   www-data       4096 May 28 17:15 railsapp1
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu www-data       4096 Apr 29 09:05 var
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `ls -l /home/test/www`

Comment: I have updated my question that now shows the output of the above command.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. It solved my problem. I had an `.htaccess` file which was overriding my apache configurations.

Comment: But index.php is not getting opened by default now if I keep only index.php.

Comment: I finally changed `AllowOverride All` to `AllowOverride None` to get everything working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a `.htaccess` file in `/home/test/www/`? The `AllowOverride All` stanza would allow the reading of that file, which is an Apache dynamic configuration file for that directory. It's contents override the configuration directives in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`.